# Databind' is not a member of 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer'

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

ive being trying to cope with this problem but still. I need your help. Im having the following error message:

```
Databind' is not a member of 'CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer'
```

in my code:

Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1()
            Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter
            Dim ds As New presbydbDataSet

```
        'Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT personal_details.fn, training.training_level FROM personal_details INNER JOIN training ON Staff_ID WHERE personal_details.staff_ID='" + detailsFrm.Label13.Text + "'", conn)




Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM personal_details WHERE personal_details.staff_ID='" + detailsFrm.Label13.Text + "'; SELECT * FROM training WHERE training.staff_ID='" + detailsFrm.Label13.Text + "'", conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds)
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
        rpt.Subreports.Item("personal_detailsRpt").SetDataSource(ds.Tables("personal_details"))
        rpt.Subreports.Item("trainingRpt").SetDataSource(ds.Tables("training"))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind()
```

Im using vb.net and these are the imports Im using:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Configuration
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer
```

Please how can I get rid of this error? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Forms [`CrystalReportViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227125.aspx) class doesn't have a `DataBind` method - simply remove that line and it should work.

[`DataBind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d.aspx) is typically used with ASP.NET controls.